# React list with no keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of *number* that I wish to render in a tabular form. The array is returned from an API call, not generated by my app.

The data may change but is unlikely to do so, and in any case there are only twenty odd values, so re-rendering the whole table is not really a problem.

A simple `data.map(value => <td>{value}</td>` should do it.

But I keep getting an `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` warning. Is there any way that I can tell React that there is no key and that I wish it to re-render the whole table if anything changes.

Alternatively, is there any way that I can generate a unique key for each entry? The data items are not guaranteed to be unique.

I should add that I understand what keys are for and why they are useful, but in this instance I do not have any and the easiest thing would be not to use them, since there is unlikely to be a re-render.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the index as the key. I think its worth reiterating that using the index as the key only works fine in the very specific scenario that the OP is facing.

This is particularly annoying when requirements change and all of sudden the list is being modified. This shows up as items not being updated during the render because the item updated has the same key (the index), its value is different, but react only cares about the key.

In cases where your data has no unique key. You should use some function that generates a unique id for each item. A simple version of that function just increments a global counter:

```
// Declared globally (as in attached to window object or equivalent)
var myuniqueidcounter = 0;
function uniqueId() {
    myuniqueidcounter += 1
    return myuniqueidcounter;
}


// Do this in the props change or whereever your data gets passed in
let keyedData = data.map(value => Object.assign(value, { Id: uniqueId() });

// In render
data.map(value => <td key={value.Id}>{value}</td>
```

That way, on multiple render calls, the ids returned are always unique. We assign the key when we get the data to avoid having to re-render the entire list on each call to `render()`.

However, this case is actually pretty rare as you can usually find *some* combination of the backing data that will produce a unique key for each entry.

**If you do go index-as-key**

[This article lists 3 conditions](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) that should be met when choosing index-as-key approach that I think is a good check list:

> 1. The list and items are static–they are not computed and do not change;
> 2. The items in the list have no ids;
> 3. The list is never reordered or filtered.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it addresses the issue of  'The data may change but is unlikely to do so'  and explains the issues surrounding using index as the key.

Answer (score 3):

```
data.map((value,index) =>{ 
  <td key={index}>{value}</td>}
)
```

or

```
  data.map((value,index) =>{ 
       let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000+1)
      <td key={i}>{value}</td>}
   )
```

You can use `index` as your key as it is unique each time

Comment: Would this cause the view to never be re-rendered if the contents of the array change but its length doesn't?

Comment: @Juan Mendes if array is in state and it changes , its obvious it re-render but it doesnot matter for `index`

Comment: I thought it may not re-render because the index would never change, but that doesn't happen, it does re-render everything, it's just that if you had a real key, it would just move the items around and would not need to re-render anything if only the order changed

Comment: Thats wrong, using index as a key is not recommended in react this is because if you push or pop items the `td` or any list will not render properly. Take a look at this http://output.jsbin.com/wohima

Comment: yes you can use id but as when there is no id index is only option left

Comment: with the math random, it's a bad practice. the first is also.
because you may have intersected keys.
and it may lead for eample clicking on one element but other is affected.

Comment: Using `Math.random` is not just a bad practice, it's completely useless because a new key is set on each render, which means React will never be able to use these keys properly. This answer should be removed, as it may mislead anybody trying to fix this warning

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question asked, it might be worth saying that there is an another solution to this that doesn't use keys:

e.g. The following will complain about not having unique keys:

```
React.createElement('div', {}, [<span>1</span>, <span>2</span>]);
```

However, the following renders all children with no problems (This is what JSX transformed to JS looks like for nodes with multiple children):

```
React.createElement('div', {}, <span>1</span>, <span>2</span>);
```

So if you have e.g. a smallish list of generated react element fragments and unique keys don't offer and advantage in your situation, you can do:

```
React.createElement.apply(null, ['div', {}, ...elementList])
```

Notes:

1. elementList is passed as arguments to React.createElement which might be an issue if the list is huge.
2. It will re-render all the children with each render.
3. Using unique keys is generally the recommended approach, and is more performant for re-rendering.
4. However there are occasions where you just want to render in a single shot and don't care about re-rendering, or the data is not structured in a way that you can make good use of unique keys. You can use this as a work-around if you really need to.